# Populating dependent dropdown list using Python and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, drop-down-menu

I have a web app with a form which takes two inputs, a file name and a sprint number.

The first one, which takes the file name, is a dynamically populated list which retrieves the list of CSV files in a specific directory and populates the form list accordingly.

Each of those CSV files has some duplicate sprint numbers in them (like 2012, 2027 etc). After selecting from the first drop down, I want the second drop down list to populate with a list of all the unique sprint numbers from the chosen CSV file name. These unique sprint numbers could probably be generated using a python script, and then results must somehow be used to populate the second drop down list.

See picture for a better idea.

[Webpage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyH6k.png)

Does anyone know how to approach this?

```
<form action="{{ url_for('output_burndown_chart') }}" method="post">
    <label for="file_name">File Name:</label><br>
    <!-- <input type="text" name="file_name"><br><br> -->
    <select id="file_name" name="file_name">
        {% for i in dir_files %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="sprint_number">Sprint Number:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="sprint_number"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/burndown', methods=['GET','POST'])
def output_burndown_chart():
    if request.method == "POST":
        sprint_num = request.form['sprint_number']
        file_name = request.form['file_name']
        dir_name = "./files"
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
        df_final = burndown_gen(file_path, sprint_num) 
        return render_template('test.html', df_final=df_final, sprint_num=sprint_num)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        dir_files = os.listdir('./files/')
        print(dir_files)
        return render_template('burndown_form.html',dir_files=dir_files)
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Currently you just explained what you want. Though you should include your code and make your question specifically about that code. We can help you from that point.

Comment: Sorry. I really want to know the approach to take. There's no code to show really since I don't know how ot start.

Comment: No, worries. Thanks for including the python and HTML. Currently you only have 1 dropdown (`<select>`) element in your HTML. Shouldn't there be a second one as well? The second one will be populated based on the result of the first select element through AJAX.

Comment: This is what you should try: 1. Populate the first `<select>` field within the flask template. 2. Use JavaScript to detect user input (change) in that first field and make a `fetch` request to the server. Use the response to populate the second `<select>` field. 3. Submit your form.